# Meteor.js deploy for web and mobile native app, one code-base

Tags: javascript, android, mobile, meteor, modulus.io

So this maybe a silly question, but i guess I'm missing something.

I host my meteor app in modulus.com.
The goal is to have a single code-base for all devices and the web, fetching from the same database.
So everything happens in the web is immediately synced with the mobile app or vice versa.

Should i provide different builds (different modulus projects [web, ios, android]) all connected to the same db to make it all work as one application?

A single build will do?

How will this work?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use the `--server` option to specify which Meteor server your built mobile app should point to. This way, you have one Meteor backend running the web app, Android app, and iOS app. This should work just fine with Modulus.

Comment: thanks, you mean the meteor build options --mobile-settings and --server settings?
Is there any modulus cli option for those??

Comment: There are no changes necessary from Modulus' point of view. Basically, you just need to tell the iOS app bundle or Android APK which server it should connect to. --server will just be the URL of your app on modulus, like "myappdomain.com" or "something.modulus.io".